# what side effects can happen for returning messages back to kafka queue

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We want to apply a retry mechanism using kafka. We willing to counter number of attempts before exhausting.

Doing it this way:

Switch consumer to to manual commit and commit only after massage finish it's 'processing' successfully (finished internal logic)

In case message fail we will return it back to the same kafka queue after appending it's headers with counter=counter+1

consumer will validate if counter=3 times we will forward to another queue

thoughts of what implication this can raise?

Comment: As long as you have enough broker storage to store  up to 3x the amount of data and you dont need to use any standard Kafka consumer (like Kafka Connect) that cannot easily filter those messages out except the most "recent one", seems fine...

Comment: I would advise against it, at least not to the same topic, produce to retry topic topic.strike.two strike.three and then to dlt , kafka records are not dequeue/deleted upon consumption, I guess you can produce the same record again to the same topic as long as you keep your logic and reading the headers for filtering correctly, @OneCricketeer you were joking right? Not using kafka api ? So why using kafka at first place?

Comment: You don't "return" the records as they were never "left"

Comment: @Ran I meant that the filter would need to be built into every consumer client manually

Comment: what about the implication of the manual commit? wont it put anything on a risk?